# Как запустить файл docx через приложение на Python?

Tags: python, pyqt5, docx

Можно, чтобы файл запускался даже просто в самом ворде, но можно ли так сделать чтобы запуск этого документа происходил именно при нажатии на кнопку?

Answer (score 1):

Для определения нажатия на кнопку используйте `button.clicked.connect` для открытия Word `os.system('start Doc1.docx')` Простейший пример:

```py
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton('Button', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.show()

    def on_click(self):
        os.system('start Doc1.docx')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! 3 часа пытался сам, но в итоге спросил.

Comment: @развлекательна5five если ответ вам помог вы можете ответить его как решение или проголосовать за него https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers